# Very simple function, but doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Please tell me what is the problem in this script:

```
$("#mydiv").click(function() 
    {
        console.log("something");
    }, function()
    {
        console.log("something");
    });
```

It doesn't make second `console`.

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you want it to do both of those fucntions at the same time, right?

Comment: if i want both of them, i'll write `{function1(){...};function2(){...}}`... i try to understand what i must wrote, to make function one by one? ie(i expect function2 to run after function1, not same time...)

Comment: see solution by bigrockshow for the execution sequence dependancy case which works because javascript is single threaded. IF you wish to have these functions private to the event, that can be done also with properly constructed event javascript.

Comment: See my answer for private functions executed in sequence in a click event.

Answer (score 4):

[`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) only takes one function.  What are you expecting out of the second function?

To have the second function run after the first function, just put it at the end of the first function.  If the first function does something asynchronously, then you'll need to attach your second function as a callback to the first's result.

```
$('#mydiv').click(function () {
    console.log('first something');
    console.log('second something');
});
```

or maybe like:

```
$('#mydiv').click(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(function () {
        console.log('second something');
    });
});
```

Comment: i need function two  to run after function1, not the same time, is it possible?(ie. if in function1 i have something which takes 500ms, i need function two to run after 500ms, but without using `setTimeout`...)

Answer (score 2):

You can probably just write your two functions as actual functions, then call each in order from your anonymous functions.  Like this:

```
function a()
{
  console.log("something");
}

function b()
{
  console.log("something");
}

$("#id").click(function(){
  a();
  b();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can bind two functions on one event like this. Unless it is designed for it, like hover for example.

Comment: and what .hover does is bind two two other events to the two functions.

Comment: Exactly, it is just a shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) takes only one handler at time. I guess you need to call it twice:

```
$("#mydiv").click(function() 
{
    console.log("something 1");
});
$("#mydiv").click(function()
{
    console.log("something 2");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing here to execute the second anonymous (unnamed)  function.

EDIT: IF what you want is to bind the two actions of a "click" you can bind the .mousedown and .mouseup functions instead of the singlular .click

EDIT2:  Based on comments, produce a private, sequence of execution functions:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
    var one = function(){
        alert('one');
    };
    var two= function(){
        alert('two');
    };
    one();
    two();
});
```

To see this in action visit: http://jsfiddle.net/R7aT3/